# Post multiple values through php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, phpmyadmin

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#update_item").change(function (e) {
        var update_item = $("#update_item").serialize();

        $.post("item.php", {"update_item": update_item}, function (data) {
            $('#details').html(data);
        });
    });  
});

</script>

<select name="update_item"  multiple="multiple" class="form-control" style="width:59%" id="update_item">
    <option value="fff">fffffff</option>
    <option value="ffff">Select Supplier</option>
    <?php 
    $result = mysql_query("select * from item");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['item_name'];?>"><?php echo $row['item_name'];?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
<div id="details">
    hii
</div>
```

Current output: `update_item=fff&update_item=ffff&update_item=fdgdfgjkljklkj`

Expected Output: `fff,ffff,fdgdfgjkljklkj` (implode post values).

Comment: try sending json or array

Comment: where is your item.php, what is it doing?

Comment: We need to see how item.php is.. If you're outputting from item.php using json_encode, then you just need to add "json" to your post request.

Comment: it will display update_item name and one input field for every update_item ..

Comment: echo $_POST['update_item']; this is item.php include .. but i need it in array format .. i want to add one input for every selected items

Comment: Why not read out the multiple values like this: $items=$_POST['update_item'];
 if ($items){
  foreach ($items as $item){ ... $item }
 }

Comment: yes .. but the value is not taking in array format .. can u send me proper code ..

Comment: Item.php code :<?php 
echo $_POST['update_item'];
?>

Answer (score 0):

You should define your HTML variable as an array ('update_item[]') and then serialize it so when you do:

```
var_dump($_POST['update_item'])
```

there will be an array data type, check:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#update_item").change(function (e) {   
        $.post("item.php", $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            $('#details').html(data);
        });
    });  
});

</script>

<select name="update_item[]"  multiple="multiple" class="form-control" style="width:59%" id="update_item">
    <option value="fff">fffffff</option>
    <option value="ffff">Select Supplier</option>
    <?php 
    $result = mysql_query("select * from item");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['item_name'];?>"><?php echo $row['item_name'];?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
<div id="details">
    hii
</div>
```

Hope it helps!